# java 8 Nashorn engine not able to compare dates

Tags: javascript, java, date, java-8, nashorn

I m suppose to compare two dates with Java 8 Nashorn engine. However it is not comparing dates correctly.

My Java Code:

```
Date start = new Date();

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

Date end = cal.getTime();

engine.put("start", start); // engine is  ScriptEngine
engine.put("end", end);

assertTrue((boolean)engine.eval("start < end")); //This assert is failing

//if I change dates to long it is working
engine.put("start", start.getTime()); 
engine.put("end", end.getTime());

assertTrue((boolean)engine.eval("start < end")); //This will now work
```

However I don't want to convert date to long because of some other requirements. Please suggest where I am making the mistake.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Nashnorn, [`new java.util.Date()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and [`new Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) produce completely different objects. And it makes sense, since the functionality of either object differs a lot. Nashorn internally uses `jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.NativeDate`.

The later, native JS, can be safely compared with `<` and `>`. For the former, the comparison will be purely by address in memory.

To work with less and greater operators, I recommend to convert Java dates to NativeDate when populating engine's global context.

One possible way of doing it would be

```
Date start = new Date();
ScriptObjectMirror jsDate = (ScriptObjectMirror) engine.eval("new Date();")
jsDate.callMember("setTime",start.getTime()); 
engine.put("start", jsDate);
engine.eval("print(start.constructor + ':' + start)");
```

Prints `"function Date() { [native code] }:Sat Jul 23 2016 19:05:53 GMT-0400 (EDT)"`

However

```
engine.put("javaStart", new Date());
engine.eval("print(javaStart.constructor + ':' + javaStart)");
```

prints `"undefined:Sat Jul 23 19:05:53 EDT 2016"`